# A different exception name is shown in the error log

Tags: hibernate, exception

My Hibernate Object requires an ID to be manually assigned before saving. But I forgot to assign it so this error log appeared:

```
ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - IdentifierGenerationException occurred when processing request: [POST] /hrims/hapum/maintenance/department/save
Stacktrace follows:
Message: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): ph.gov.nhmfc.hapum.Department
    Line | Method
->>   24 | save             in ph.gov.nhmfc.DomainService$$EQDMPY5t
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|    191 | save             in ph.gov.nhmfc.hapum.DepartmentService$$EQDM563D
|     85 | save . . . . . . in ph.gov.nhmfc.hapum.maintenance.DepartmentController
|    198 | doFilter         in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter . . . . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|    449 | executeChain     in org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter
|    365 | call . . . . . . in org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1
|     90 | doCall           in org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable
|     83 | call . . . . . . in     ''
|    383 | execute          in org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject
|    362 | doFilterInternal in org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter
|    125 | doFilter         in org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter
|   1145 | runWorker . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run              in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run . . . . . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

So that is why I tried to catch the `IdentifierGenerationException`:

```
try {
    hibernate.save(insert: true)
}
catch(IdentifierGenerationException e) {
    errors.push("An identifier should be assigned for this record before saving.")
}
catch(Exception e) {
    println(e.getClass())
    errors.push("An error has occured.")
}
```

On my surprise, instead of going to the first `catch` statement, it then went to the second one and printed:

```
class org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException
```

What gives? Is is safe to assume that all `IdentifierGenerationException` will be handled by `HibernateSystemException`. What if there are other `Exception` that are *"categorized"* under the `HibernateSystemException`?

This is now my `try-catch` statement looked like:

```
try {
    hibernate.save(insert: true)
}
catch(IdentifierGenerationException e) {
    errors.push("An identifier should be assigned for this record before saving.")
}
catch(HibernateSystemException e) {
    errors.push("An identifier should be assigned for this record before saving.")
}
catch(Exception e) {
    errors.push("An unidentifieable error has occured.")
}
```

I'm using Hibernate 4 on Grails 2.4.4.

Comment: Please add complete stacktrace of the exception to your post. For exception handling with Spring, you have to use `DataAccessException`

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it is seems `IdentifierGenerationException` is the nested exception of `HibernateSystemException`. So you should not try to catch `HibernateSystemException` if you only want to only catch object without id, Since `HibernateSystemException` can also be caused by other than `IdentifierGenerationException`.

You should check the cause of the exception, then check if the nested exception is instanceof `IdentifierGenerationException`. Or check the object id is null or not.